# Why $f$ has to be invertible?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Let $V,W$ be two $(n+1)$-dim. vector spaces.

> **Proposition:** Let $P(V), P(W)$ be $n$-dim. projective spaces. 
>   $\tau \colon P(V) \to P(W)$ is a projective transformation, if it comes from an invertible linear map $f \colon V \to W$ such that $\tau\left(\left[v\right]\right) = \left[f(v)\right]$.

**Question:**
Why $f$ has to be invertible?

Comment: Probably part of the definition of "transformation".

Comment: @GregoryGrant: No! Unless $f$ is invertible, $\tau$ is not defined on the whole of $P(V).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not invertible, then $\ker f$ is at least one dimensional. Choose a non-zero vector $v \in \ker f.$ Then $f(v)=0.$ In this case what is the "image" of $\tau$ at the point $[v]$?

Comment: Well, $\tau\left(\left[v\right]\right)= \left[f(v)\right] = \left[0\right]$. But this equation is not defined.

Comment: What is the meaning of "$[0]$" in the projective space?

Comment: I thought $\left[0\right]$ is not in $P(W)$.

Comment: Yes! That's why the map $\tau$ can not be define on the whole of $P(V)$ unless you choose $f$ to be invertible.